# Использование ресурсов без распаковки

Tags: c#, .net

Можно ли поместить в библеотеку необходимые ресурсы и пользоваться ими без распаковки?

Например, моя DLL является оболочкой над неуправляемой или оболочкой над приложением, где есть API в виде командной строки.

Я могу это поместить в ресурсы и нераспаковывать, что бы использовать*

Или такого не возможно добиться?